# Javascript/Node.js: data patching scheme

Tags: javascript, node.js, diff, patch, revision

I'm writing a little app in node. I have posts that I want wiki-like revisions for. I'm also saving the post very frequently as they're being edited, so I do not want to save full revisions on each edit.

Is anyone aware of any existing schemes for storing patches rather than revisions? This will be json/plaintext, no need to diff binaries or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you settle for simple last-edit-wins logic, this is quite complicated (actually, it will still be if you do :). You might be interested in the [wave protocol](http://www.waveprotocol.org/), open-sourced.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by reading the blog post [Time and Space Tradeoffs in Version Control Storage](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/time_space_tradeoffs.html) by Eric Sink (SourceGear founder) where he discusses the very question you ask:

> Storage is one of the most difficult
>   challenges for a version control
>   system.  For every file, we must store
>   every version that has ever existed. 
>   The logical size of a version control
>   repository never shrinks.  It just
>   keeps growing and growing, and every
>   old version needs to remain available.
>
> So, what is the best way to store
>   every version of everything?